# How to list (dump) context content in debug purposes?

Tags: python

Let's say I have an operator

```
class FooOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "foo.bar"
    bl_label = "Dummy operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print(context)
```

So, then it invokes, I want to see what is available in context, list of functions or values that are available to use, but output only says:

```
<bpy_struct, Context at 0x562a6cda4dd8>
```

I tried `print(context.keys())` and `pprint` but nothing really helps.

How can I print content of this `bpy_struct` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Via `Context.copy()`**

Conveniently there is a `copy()` method that returns context as a dictionary.

```
>>> print(C)
<bpy_struct, Context at 0x7f771bd250c8>

>>> c = C.copy()
>>> for k, v in c.items():
...     k, v
...     
('active_annotation_layer', None)
('active_bone', None)
('active_editable_fcurve', None)
('active_gpencil_frame', None)
('active_gpencil_layer', None)
('active_object', bpy.data.objects['Text'])
('active_operator', <bpy_struct, Operator("TEXT_OT_run_script") at 0x7f771304bd88>)
('active_pose_bone', None)

etcetera, etcetera

('visible_objects', [bpy.data.objects['Lamp'], bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.data.objects['Text']])
('visible_pose_bones', None)
('weight_paint_object', None)
('window', bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...Window)
('window_manager', bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'])
('workspace', bpy.data.workspaces['Scripting'])
```

Comment: `pprint(context.copy())` works fine, thanks